# HTTP2 Stream not working on safari iOS

Tags: ios, streaming, http2

I'm testing http2 streaming across browser, but I can't make it work on iOS Safari. Don't have an apple desktop atm.

node server:

```
const http2 = require('http2')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http2.createSecureServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('../certs/localhost-privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../certs/localhost-cert.pem')
})

const page = fs.readFileSync('full.html.br')

let middle = 300

server.on('error', (err) => console.error(err))

server.on('stream', (stream, headers) => {
  stream.respond({
    'content-type': 'text/HTML',
    ':status': 200,
    'Content-Encoding': 'br'
  })
  stream.write(page.slice(0, middle))
  stream.end(page.slice(middle, page.length - 1))
})

server.listen(8443)
```

On iOS it simply displays a blank page. On Linux and Windows it works correctly. It also works with gzip, only brotli is broken.

Comment: What version of iOS? Only added in 11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=brotli

Comment: thank you @BarryPollard :) :) Brotli alone works, but brotli + streaming doesn't. iOS is updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that was a typo but this line:

```
'Content-Encoding': 'brotli'
```

should actually be:

```
'Content-Encoding': 'br'
```

When I do that it works works fine on iPhone (iOS 11.4), iPad (iOS 11.4) and Safari on a Mac, otherwise it displays rubbish. But it does the same in Chrome when the incorrect content encoding is used.

If the above is a typo, then I'd suggest your full.html.br maybe has a problem?